# Xtend: How to convert Integer to String?

Tags: string, integer, type-conversion, xtend

What is the preferred way to convert an Integer into a String in Xtend? Is there a better way than this?

```
var int port = 12345
var String portStr = "" + port
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var portString = port.toString
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just curious where I could find that in an 'official' documentation...